# How would I change my yesterday SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

How would I change my SELECT for yesterday. Here is the code:

```
      SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT tracking.ip) AS user_hits FROM user, tracking WHERE tracking.user_id = $user_id GROUP BY $user_id ORDER BY user_hits LIMIT 1
```

That is the code I use to SELECT yesterday only. Here is how my database looks like:

```
      Database values:  2013.12.14
```

How would I change my SELECT?

Comment: No where near enough information. What is going wrong here?

Comment: It seems not to be selecting from yesterday since its missing the time I think.

Comment: This isn't a PHP question...

Comment: @user3102920 You need to include the date selection in the `WHERE` clause somewhere

Comment: We still don't know where you date is located in your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running a query just to see what limits are you trying to set at lowerbound and upperbound for your time period

```
SELECT 
DATE_SUB(  CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AS lowerlimit, 
DATE_SUB(  CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 SECOND ) AS upperlimit
```

You'll see that the results are today at 00:00 and today at 23:59 respectively. If you want to  go back one day, then substract an extra day of each

```
SELECT 
DATE_SUB(  CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 2 DAY ) AS lowerlimit, 
DATE_SUB(  CURDATE( )  , INTERVAL '1 0:0:1' DAY_SECOND ) AS upperlimit
```

So your query should be something like

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB
FROM tableA
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(  CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 2 DAY ) AND  DATE_SUB(  CURDATE( )  , INTERVAL '1 0:0:1' DAY_SECOND )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE_SUB(CONCAT(CURDATE(), '00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`.